# How to stop carousel slider in Cypress?

Tags: jquery, slider, carousel, cypress

When I am using `Cypress.$('.banner-carousel').carousel({interval: false,});` to stop the slider I am getting `Cypress.$(...).carousel is not a function` error. How can I stop the slider otherwise?

Comment: We need more context in order to help you. How would you stop the carousel as a user in your web app/website?

Comment: @ManuelAbascal The user is not able to stop the carousel. But I need to stop the carousel to get my page frozen to do some visual testing.

Comment: Can you share more code about the carousel? Maybe a simple jsfiddle? I need your fill the gap in order to assist you. Is this carousel built with vanilla js, jquery, react, angular, etc?

Comment: The main framework of the website is Next.js

Comment: I think instead of stopping the carousel, you should assert the current `img` HTML element `src`'s attribute & after an `x` amount of time changes it's value & you assert the new value once again. If you absolutely need to assert visual testing. You could use a plugin from this [list](https://docs.cypress.io/plugins/#visual-testing)

Comment: The problem is that I am doing assertion of another elements, and the carousell is in background and it is dynamic. I need to freeze it to get static snapshots every time I run my tests.

Comment: You might be able to use [cy.clock()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/clock.html#Examples) if the carousel timing is based on `setInterval()`.

Comment: Is the interval made by class/property? Can you snapshot at least the inspect part of the element so we can see what properties it has?

Comment: @RichardMatsen Yes, it worked. Thank you so much. You can answer the question and I will metnion it as a solution!

Comment: Cheers, glad that worked. You can post your working test in an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `cy.clock()` and it solved my problem as my carousel was based on `setInterval()`.